# how to fetch and delete old duplicate records from table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

```
select * from tmp_dib;

1360       DIBAKAR  SE1  
1360       DIBAKAR  SE  
1361       JAI          SE1  
1361       JAI          SE  
1365       NITISH   SE1  
1365       NITISH   SE
```

where `SE1` are the old record and `SE` is new record.

By the below query I am getting the New record.

```
select a.*  from tmp_dib a where rowid >
(select min(rowid) from tmp_dib b where a.ID=b.ID);

1360    DIBAKAR SE  
1361    JAI SE  
1365    NITISH  SE
```

Please help me with a query to get the record for old record. I want to fetch the old record and want to delete.

My desired output:

```
1360    DIBAKAR     SE1  
1361    JAI         SE1  
1365    NITISH      SE1
```

this is a sample table(not actual table/data).. i have a table with around 10k data and that is in a live system. so i need to identified the entry with old record.

Comment: Why don't you simply extend the query for fetching old records to delete old records? `DELETE from tmp_dib a where rowid >
(select min(rowid) from tmp_dib b where a.ID=b.ID);`

Comment: Your query doesn't implement the logic that you think it does, because ROWID is a pseudocolumn that has nothing to do with the age of a record.

Comment: How do you determine which one is old and new. Do you have any date to decide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to fetch and delete the old records using rowid.

```
DELETE FROM tmp_dib A WHERE ROWID <
(SELECT max(ROWID) FROM tmp_dib b WHERE A.ID=b.ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you reference the third column, as opposed to using the id's?

You haven't specified what the column names are but I'll assume it's called Column3

```
DELETE TMP_DIB
WHERE Column3 = 'SE1'
```

Comment: Yes..... based on the information provided, the rowid is totally useless and this will do wxactly what you want.

Comment: Hi actually .. this is a sample table(not actual data).. i have a table with around 10k data and that is in a live system. so i need to identified the entry with old record.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a Last update date in the table, right? if yes, you can use the below query

```
delete from tmp_dib where id||last update date in (select id,min(last update date) from tmpbid group by id having count(*)>1)
```